# Any downside to using {% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}

Tags: flask, bootstrap-4

When going through different flask and bootstrap tutorials, there seem to be some suggesting creating a base.html that uses {% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %} and another set that recommend just copying in the starting template (or similar) from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start

Is there a downside to just using {% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}?  Will I run into issues at some point for things I can't do?